# Safety of passing HBITMAP handle from unmanaged to managed code for created a System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

I'm pretty new to managed/unmanaged interop, so I'm looking to get some opinions on how safe the following procedure is for getting a bitmap from unmanaged C++ to managed C#. The basic idea is:

1. C# calls an interop function, `FetchImage`, which is in the unmanaged C++. It passes an `out int` param. `FetchImage` has a corresponding `long *` param.
2. In C++, `FetchImage` creates a `CBitmap` somewhere safe, ie not local, draws something on it, uses `HandleToLong()` to convert the bitmap's `HBITMAP` handle to a `long`, stores it in the param for the C#, and returns.
3. Back in C#, the `out int` param is converted to an `IntPtr` and uses `System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap` to copy the data and produce a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object.
4. C# then calls another interop function, `ReleaseImage`.
5. In C++, `ReleaseImage` frees the resources associated with the `CBitmap` it created earlier.

That's the gist for the impatient. More specific code examples below.

C++ interop definitions for the functions:

```
namespace {
    std::unique_ptr< CBitmap > bitty;
}
HRESULT __stdcall Helper::FetchImage( /*[out]*/ long * hBitmap )
{
    bitty.reset( new CBitmap );

    // call CreateBitmap and then draw something,
    // ensure it's not selected into a DC when done

    *hBitmap = HandleToLong( bitty->GetSafeHandle() );
    return S_OK;
}
HRESULT __stdcall Helper::ReleaseImage()
{
    bitty.reset();
    return S_OK;
}
```

IDL prototypes for the interop functions, which are wrapped in a helper class in C#:

```
[id(1)] HRESULT FetchImage( long * hBitmap );
[id(2)] HRESULT ReleaseImage();
```

Produces these C# prototypes in the helper class:

```
void FetchImage( out int hBitmap );
void ReleaseImage();
```

And the C# that calls them looks kind of like this:

```
int ret;
helper.FetchImage( out ret );
Bitmap b = Image.FromHbitmap( (IntPtr)ret );
helper.ReleaseImage();
// do anything I want with b
```

The only issue I've come up with on my own is the case of a call to `FetchImage` or `ReleaseImage` from somewhere else getting things out of sync. So I'll probably have a list of `CBitmap`s instead of just one, then pass the handle back to `ReleaseImage` so it'll only destroy the one from the matching `FetchImage` call.

Are there any gotchas I'm not aware of? I do have this working, I just wanted to make sure I'm not doing something dangerous because I don't know any better.

Comment: The argument types are wrong, should be IntPtr and HANDLE.  You can release the CBitmap right away, FromHbitmap makes a copy so the painful and risky ReleaseImage() isn't needed.

Comment: @Hans Except that the CBitmap is created in the unmanaged C++ code. How will that code know to release it unless told?

Comment: You've got a point, can't do it until FromHbitmap() executes.

Answer (score 2):

You could just declare that it is the caller's responsibility to free the HBITMAP.  That would simplify your C++ code since you could remove the ReleaseImage method.  Example:

```
HRESULT __stdcall Helper::FetchImage( /*[out]*/ HBITMAP * hBitmap )
{
    *hBitmap = NULL; // assume failure
    unique_ptr<CBitmap> bmp(new CBitmap);

    // call CreateBitmap and then draw something,
    // ensure it's not selected into a DC when done

    *hBitmap = (HBITMAP)bmp->Detach();
    return S_OK;
}
// Delete ReleaseImage and all supporting global variables...

// C# example:
IntPtr ret;
helper.FetchImage( out ret );
try {
    Bitmap b = Image.FromHbitmap( ret );
} finally {
    DeleteObject(ret); // pinvoke call into GDI
}
```

Alternatively, you could look into returning an [IPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680761%28VS.85%29.aspx) using [OleCreatePictureIndirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694511%28VS.85%29.aspx).  That provides some advantages:

- Caller frees the returned image using standard COM reference counting.  That generally frees the caller from worrying about freeing the returned image (unless the caller is another C++ program that needs to manually call IUnknown::Release).
- Better compatibility with other COM-enabled languages, like VBA / VB6.  IPicture is the standard way of passing around a picture in COM.